# Dask client + read_sql_table: distributed.protocol.core - CRITICAL - Failed to Serialize

Tags: python, dask, dask-dataframe

Trying to run `read_sql_table` using a `dask.distributed Client`, where the table is a query as I don't want to get the whole table. Example below.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.distributed import Client

client = Client()
sql = select([schema.datetime,     # DateTime format
              schema.id]) \        # UUID
        .select_from(schema) \     # schema class (see below)
        .where(schema.datetime.between(start_dt, end_dt))
table = aliased(sql, name='table')
response = dd.read_sql_table(table=table, uri='uri', schema='schema', index_col='datetime')
```

For `print(response)`, I get the expected output:

```
Dask DataFrame Structure:
                        swing_id
npartitions=1                   
2020-08-03 07:16:59.590   object
2020-08-29 23:34:44.980      ...
Dask Name: from-delayed, 2 tasks
```

However when I got to use the `dask.dataframe` like `print(response.head())`, I get a `Failed to Serialize` error:

```
distributed.protocol.core - CRITICAL - Failed to Serialize
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\distributed\protocol\core.py", line 50, in dumps
    data = {
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\distributed\protocol\core.py", line 51, in <dictcomp>
    key: serialize(
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\distributed\protocol\serialize.py", line 277, in serialize
    raise TypeError(msg, str(x)[:10000])
TypeError: ('Could not serialize object of type tuple.', "(<function safe_head at 0x00000000053B88B0>, (<function check_meta at 0x0000000005387EE0>, (<function apply at 0x0000000002AB3280>, <function _read_sql_chunk at 0x0000000005450AF0>, [<sqlalchemy.sql.selectable.Select at 0x99f8ca0; Select object>, 'postgresql://tirisdspgadmin@tirisdspgserver:wsiNTobyx8opPo2imfCB@tirisdspgserver.postgres.database.azure.com/mav', Empty DataFrame\nColumns: [swing_id]\nIndex: []], (<class 'dict'>, [['engine_kwargs', (<class 'dict'>, [])], ['index_col', 'start_time']])), Empty DataFrame\nColumns: [swing_id]\nIndex: [], 'from_delayed'), 5)")
distributed.comm.utils - ERROR - ('Could not serialize object of type tuple.', "(<function safe_head at 0x00000000053B88B0>, (<function check_meta at 0x0000000005387EE0>, (<function apply at 0x0000000002AB3280>, <function _read_sql_chunk at 0x0000000005450AF0>, [<sqlalchemy.sql.selectable.Select at 0x99f8ca0; Select object>, 'postgresql://tirisdspgadmin@tirisdspgserver:wsiNTobyx8opPo2imfCB@tirisdspgserver.postgres.database.azure.com/mav', Empty DataFrame\nColumns: [swing_id]\nIndex: []], (<class 'dict'>, [['engine_kwargs', (<class 'dict'>, [])], ['index_col', 'start_time']])), Empty DataFrame\nColumns: [swing_id]\nIndex: [], 'from_delayed'), 5)")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\distributed\comm\utils.py", line 34, in _to_frames
    protocol.dumps(
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\distributed\protocol\core.py", line 50, in dumps
    data = {
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\distributed\protocol\core.py", line 51, in <dictcomp>
    key: serialize(
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\distributed\protocol\serialize.py", line 277, in serialize
    raise TypeError(msg, str(x)[:10000])
TypeError: ('Could not serialize object of type tuple.', "(<function safe_head at 0x00000000053B88B0>, (<function check_meta at 0x0000000005387EE0>, (<function apply at 0x0000000002AB3280>, <function _read_sql_chunk at 0x0000000005450AF0>, [<sqlalchemy.sql.selectable.Select at 0x99f8ca0; Select object>, 'postgresql://tirisdspgadmin@tirisdspgserver:wsiNTobyx8opPo2imfCB@tirisdspgserver.postgres.database.azure.com/mav', Empty DataFrame\nColumns: [swing_id]\nIndex: []], (<class 'dict'>, [['engine_kwargs', (<class 'dict'>, [])], ['index_col', 'start_time']])), Empty DataFrame\nColumns: [swing_id]\nIndex: [], 'from_delayed'), 5)")
distributed.batched - WARNING - Error in batched write, retrying
distributed.protocol.core - CRITICAL - Failed to Serialize
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\distributed\protocol\core.py", line 50, in dumps
    data = {
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\distributed\protocol\core.py", line 51, in <dictcomp>
    key: serialize(
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\distributed\protocol\serialize.py", line 277, in serialize
    raise TypeError(msg, str(x)[:10000])
TypeError: ('Could not serialize object of type tuple.', "(<function safe_head at 0x00000000053B88B0>, (<function check_meta at 0x0000000005387EE0>, (<function apply at 0x0000000002AB3280>, <function _read_sql_chunk at 0x0000000005450AF0>, [<sqlalchemy.sql.selectable.Select at 0x99f8ca0; Select object>, 'postgresql://tirisdspgadmin@tirisdspgserver:wsiNTobyx8opPo2imfCB@tirisdspgserver.postgres.database.azure.com/mav', Empty DataFrame\nColumns: [swing_id]\nIndex: []], (<class 'dict'>, [['engine_kwargs', (<class 'dict'>, [])], ['index_col', 'start_time']])), Empty DataFrame\nColumns: [swing_id]\nIndex: [], 'from_delayed'), 5)")
distributed.comm.utils - ERROR - ('Could not serialize object of type tuple.', "(<function safe_head at 0x00000000053B88B0>, (<function check_meta at 0x0000000005387EE0>, (<function apply at 0x0000000002AB3280>, <function _read_sql_chunk at 0x0000000005450AF0>, [<sqlalchemy.sql.selectable.Select at 0x99f8ca0; Select object>, 'postgresql://tirisdspgadmin@tirisdspgserver:wsiNTobyx8opPo2imfCB@tirisdspgserver.postgres.database.azure.com/mav', Empty DataFrame\nColumns: [swing_id]\nIndex: []], (<class 'dict'>, [['engine_kwargs', (<class 'dict'>, [])], ['index_col', 'start_time']])), Empty DataFrame\nColumns: [swing_id]\nIndex: [], 'from_delayed'), 5)")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\distributed\comm\utils.py", line 34, in _to_frames
    protocol.dumps(
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\distributed\protocol\core.py", line 50, in dumps
    data = {
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\distributed\protocol\core.py", line 51, in <dictcomp>
    key: serialize(
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\distributed\protocol\serialize.py", line 277, in serialize
    raise TypeError(msg, str(x)[:10000])
TypeError: ('Could not serialize object of type tuple.', "(<function safe_head at 0x00000000053B88B0>, (<function check_meta at 0x0000000005387EE0>, (<function apply at 0x0000000002AB3280>, <function _read_sql_chunk at 0x0000000005450AF0>, [<sqlalchemy.sql.selectable.Select at 0x99f8ca0; Select object>, 'postgresql://tirisdspgadmin@tirisdspgserver:wsiNTobyx8opPo2imfCB@tirisdspgserver.postgres.database.azure.com/mav', Empty DataFrame\nColumns: [swing_id]\nIndex: []], (<class 'dict'>, [['engine_kwargs', (<class 'dict'>, [])], ['index_col', 'start_time']])), Empty DataFrame\nColumns: [swing_id]\nIndex: [], 'from_delayed'), 5)")
distributed.batched - WARNING - Error in batched write, retrying
distributed.protocol.core - CRITICAL - Failed to Serialize
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\distributed\protocol\core.py", line 50, in dumps
    data = {
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\distributed\protocol\core.py", line 51, in <dictcomp>
    key: serialize(
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\distributed\protocol\serialize.py", line 277, in serialize
    raise TypeError(msg, str(x)[:10000])
TypeError: ('Could not serialize object of type tuple.', "(<function safe_head at 0x00000000053B88B0>, (<function check_meta at 0x0000000005387EE0>, (<function apply at 0x0000000002AB3280>, <function _read_sql_chunk at 0x0000000005450AF0>, [<sqlalchemy.sql.selectable.Select at 0x99f8ca0; Select object>, 'postgresql://tirisdspgadmin@tirisdspgserver:wsiNTobyx8opPo2imfCB@tirisdspgserver.postgres.database.azure.com/mav', Empty DataFrame\nColumns: [swing_id]\nIndex: []], (<class 'dict'>, [['engine_kwargs', (<class 'dict'>, [])], ['index_col', 'start_time']])), Empty DataFrame\nColumns: [swing_id]\nIndex: [], 'from_delayed'), 5)")
distributed.comm.utils - ERROR - ('Could not serialize object of type tuple.', "(<function safe_head at 0x00000000053B88B0>, (<function check_meta at 0x0000000005387EE0>, (<function apply at 0x0000000002AB3280>, <function _read_sql_chunk at 0x0000000005450AF0>, [<sqlalchemy.sql.selectable.Select at 0x99f8ca0; Select object>, 'postgresql://tirisdspgadmin@tirisdspgserver:wsiNTobyx8opPo2imfCB@tirisdspgserver.postgres.database.azure.com/mav', Empty DataFrame\nColumns: [swing_id]\nIndex: []], (<class 'dict'>, [['engine_kwargs', (<class 'dict'>, [])], ['index_col', 'start_time']])), Empty DataFrame\nColumns: [swing_id]\nIndex: [], 'from_delayed'), 5)")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\distributed\comm\utils.py", line 34, in _to_frames
    protocol.dumps(
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\distributed\protocol\core.py", line 50, in dumps
    data = {
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\distributed\protocol\core.py", line 51, in <dictcomp>
    key: serialize(
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\distributed\protocol\serialize.py", line 277, in serialize
    raise TypeError(msg, str(x)[:10000])
TypeError: ('Could not serialize object of type tuple.', "(<function safe_head at 0x00000000053B88B0>, (<function check_meta at 0x0000000005387EE0>, (<function apply at 0x0000000002AB3280>, <function _read_sql_chunk at 0x0000000005450AF0>, [<sqlalchemy.sql.selectable.Select at 0x99f8ca0; Select object>, 'postgresql://tirisdspgadmin@tirisdspgserver:wsiNTobyx8opPo2imfCB@tirisdspgserver.postgres.database.azure.com/mav', Empty DataFrame\nColumns: [swing_id]\nIndex: []], (<class 'dict'>, [['engine_kwargs', (<class 'dict'>, [])], ['index_col', 'start_time']])), Empty DataFrame\nColumns: [swing_id]\nIndex: [], 'from_delayed'), 5)")
distributed.batched - WARNING - Error in batched write, retrying
distributed.protocol.core - CRITICAL - Failed to Serialize
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\distributed\protocol\core.py", line 50, in dumps
    data = {
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\distributed\protocol\core.py", line 51, in <dictcomp>
    key: serialize(
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\distributed\protocol\serialize.py", line 277, in serialize
    raise TypeError(msg, str(x)[:10000])
TypeError: ('Could not serialize object of type tuple.', "(<function safe_head at 0x00000000053B88B0>, (<function check_meta at 0x0000000005387EE0>, (<function apply at 0x0000000002AB3280>, <function _read_sql_chunk at 0x0000000005450AF0>, [<sqlalchemy.sql.selectable.Select at 0x99f8ca0; Select object>, 'postgresql://tirisdspgadmin@tirisdspgserver:wsiNTobyx8opPo2imfCB@tirisdspgserver.postgres.database.azure.com/mav', Empty DataFrame\nColumns: [swing_id]\nIndex: []], (<class 'dict'>, [['engine_kwargs', (<class 'dict'>, [])], ['index_col', 'start_time']])), Empty DataFrame\nColumns: [swing_id]\nIndex: [], 'from_delayed'), 5)")
distributed.comm.utils - ERROR - ('Could not serialize object of type tuple.', "(<function safe_head at 0x00000000053B88B0>, (<function check_meta at 0x0000000005387EE0>, (<function apply at 0x0000000002AB3280>, <function _read_sql_chunk at 0x0000000005450AF0>, [<sqlalchemy.sql.selectable.Select at 0x99f8ca0; Select object>, 'postgresql://tirisdspgadmin@tirisdspgserver:wsiNTobyx8opPo2imfCB@tirisdspgserver.postgres.database.azure.com/mav', Empty DataFrame\nColumns: [swing_id]\nIndex: []], (<class 'dict'>, [['engine_kwargs', (<class 'dict'>, [])], ['index_col', 'start_time']])), Empty DataFrame\nColumns: [swing_id]\nIndex: [], 'from_delayed'), 5)")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\distributed\comm\utils.py", line 34, in _to_frames
    protocol.dumps(
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\distributed\protocol\core.py", line 50, in dumps
    data = {
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\distributed\protocol\core.py", line 51, in <dictcomp>
    key: serialize(
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\distributed\protocol\serialize.py", line 277, in serialize
    raise TypeError(msg, str(x)[:10000])
TypeError: ('Could not serialize object of type tuple.', "(<function safe_head at 0x00000000053B88B0>, (<function check_meta at 0x0000000005387EE0>, (<function apply at 0x0000000002AB3280>, <function _read_sql_chunk at 0x0000000005450AF0>, [<sqlalchemy.sql.selectable.Select at 0x99f8ca0; Select object>, 'postgresql://tirisdspgadmin@tirisdspgserver:wsiNTobyx8opPo2imfCB@tirisdspgserver.postgres.database.azure.com/mav', Empty DataFrame\nColumns: [swing_id]\nIndex: []], (<class 'dict'>, [['engine_kwargs', (<class 'dict'>, [])], ['index_col', 'start_time']])), Empty DataFrame\nColumns: [swing_id]\nIndex: [], 'from_delayed'), 5)")
distributed.batched - WARNING - Error in batched write, retrying
distributed.protocol.core - CRITICAL - Failed to Serialize
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\distributed\protocol\core.py", line 50, in dumps
    data = {
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\distributed\protocol\core.py", line 51, in <dictcomp>
    key: serialize(
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\distributed\protocol\serialize.py", line 277, in serialize
    raise TypeError(msg, str(x)[:10000])
TypeError: ('Could not serialize object of type tuple.', "(<function safe_head at 0x00000000053B88B0>, (<function check_meta at 0x0000000005387EE0>, (<function apply at 0x0000000002AB3280>, <function _read_sql_chunk at 0x0000000005450AF0>, [<sqlalchemy.sql.selectable.Select at 0x99f8ca0; Select object>, 'postgresql://tirisdspgadmin@tirisdspgserver:wsiNTobyx8opPo2imfCB@tirisdspgserver.postgres.database.azure.com/mav', Empty DataFrame\nColumns: [swing_id]\nIndex: []], (<class 'dict'>, [['engine_kwargs', (<class 'dict'>, [])], ['index_col', 'start_time']])), Empty DataFrame\nColumns: [swing_id]\nIndex: [], 'from_delayed'), 5)")
distributed.comm.utils - ERROR - ('Could not serialize object of type tuple.', "(<function safe_head at 0x00000000053B88B0>, (<function check_meta at 0x0000000005387EE0>, (<function apply at 0x0000000002AB3280>, <function _read_sql_chunk at 0x0000000005450AF0>, [<sqlalchemy.sql.selectable.Select at 0x99f8ca0; Select object>, 'postgresql://tirisdspgadmin@tirisdspgserver:wsiNTobyx8opPo2imfCB@tirisdspgserver.postgres.database.azure.com/mav', Empty DataFrame\nColumns: [swing_id]\nIndex: []], (<class 'dict'>, [['engine_kwargs', (<class 'dict'>, [])], ['index_col', 'start_time']])), Empty DataFrame\nColumns: [swing_id]\nIndex: [], 'from_delayed'), 5)")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\distributed\comm\utils.py", line 34, in _to_frames
    protocol.dumps(
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\distributed\protocol\core.py", line 50, in dumps
    data = {
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\distributed\protocol\core.py", line 51, in <dictcomp>
    key: serialize(
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\distributed\protocol\serialize.py", line 277, in serialize
    raise TypeError(msg, str(x)[:10000])
TypeError: ('Could not serialize object of type tuple.', "(<function safe_head at 0x00000000053B88B0>, (<function check_meta at 0x0000000005387EE0>, (<function apply at 0x0000000002AB3280>, <function _read_sql_chunk at 0x0000000005450AF0>, [<sqlalchemy.sql.selectable.Select at 0x99f8ca0; Select object>, 'postgresql://tirisdspgadmin@tirisdspgserver:wsiNTobyx8opPo2imfCB@tirisdspgserver.postgres.database.azure.com/mav', Empty DataFrame\nColumns: [swing_id]\nIndex: []], (<class 'dict'>, [['engine_kwargs', (<class 'dict'>, [])], ['index_col', 'start_time']])), Empty DataFrame\nColumns: [swing_id]\nIndex: [], 'from_delayed'), 5)")
distributed.batched - WARNING - Error in batched write, retrying
distributed.protocol.core - CRITICAL - Failed to Serialize
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\distributed\protocol\core.py", line 50, in dumps
    data = {
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\distributed\protocol\core.py", line 51, in <dictcomp>
    key: serialize(
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\distributed\protocol\serialize.py", line 277, in serialize
    raise TypeError(msg, str(x)[:10000])
TypeError: ('Could not serialize object of type tuple.', "(<function safe_head at 0x00000000053B88B0>, (<function check_meta at 0x0000000005387EE0>, (<function apply at 0x0000000002AB3280>, <function _read_sql_chunk at 0x0000000005450AF0>, [<sqlalchemy.sql.selectable.Select at 0x99f8ca0; Select object>, 'postgresql://tirisdspgadmin@tirisdspgserver:wsiNTobyx8opPo2imfCB@tirisdspgserver.postgres.database.azure.com/mav', Empty DataFrame\nColumns: [swing_id]\nIndex: []], (<class 'dict'>, [['engine_kwargs', (<class 'dict'>, [])], ['index_col', 'start_time']])), Empty DataFrame\nColumns: [swing_id]\nIndex: [], 'from_delayed'), 5)")
distributed.comm.utils - ERROR - ('Could not serialize object of type tuple.', "(<function safe_head at 0x00000000053B88B0>, (<function check_meta at 0x0000000005387EE0>, (<function apply at 0x0000000002AB3280>, <function _read_sql_chunk at 0x0000000005450AF0>, [<sqlalchemy.sql.selectable.Select at 0x99f8ca0; Select object>, 'postgresql://tirisdspgadmin@tirisdspgserver:wsiNTobyx8opPo2imfCB@tirisdspgserver.postgres.database.azure.com/mav', Empty DataFrame\nColumns: [swing_id]\nIndex: []], (<class 'dict'>, [['engine_kwargs', (<class 'dict'>, [])], ['index_col', 'start_time']])), Empty DataFrame\nColumns: [swing_id]\nIndex: [], 'from_delayed'), 5)")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\distributed\comm\utils.py", line 34, in _to_frames
    protocol.dumps(
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\distributed\protocol\core.py", line 50, in dumps
    data = {
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\distributed\protocol\core.py", line 51, in <dictcomp>
    key: serialize(
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\distributed\protocol\serialize.py", line 277, in serialize
    raise TypeError(msg, str(x)[:10000])
TypeError: ('Could not serialize object of type tuple.', "(<function safe_head at 0x00000000053B88B0>, (<function check_meta at 0x0000000005387EE0>, (<function apply at 0x0000000002AB3280>, <function _read_sql_chunk at 0x0000000005450AF0>, [<sqlalchemy.sql.selectable.Select at 0x99f8ca0; Select object>, 'postgresql://tirisdspgadmin@tirisdspgserver:wsiNTobyx8opPo2imfCB@tirisdspgserver.postgres.database.azure.com/mav', Empty DataFrame\nColumns: [swing_id]\nIndex: []], (<class 'dict'>, [['engine_kwargs', (<class 'dict'>, [])], ['index_col', 'start_time']])), Empty DataFrame\nColumns: [swing_id]\nIndex: [], 'from_delayed'), 5)")
distributed.batched - WARNING - Error in batched write, retrying
distributed.protocol.core - CRITICAL - Failed to Serialize
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\distributed\protocol\core.py", line 50, in dumps
    data = {
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\distributed\protocol\core.py", line 51, in <dictcomp>
    key: serialize(
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\distributed\protocol\serialize.py", line 277, in serialize
    raise TypeError(msg, str(x)[:10000])
TypeError: ('Could not serialize object of type tuple.', "(<function safe_head at 0x00000000053B88B0>, (<function check_meta at 0x0000000005387EE0>, (<function apply at 0x0000000002AB3280>, <function _read_sql_chunk at 0x0000000005450AF0>, [<sqlalchemy.sql.selectable.Select at 0x99f8ca0; Select object>, 'postgresql://tirisdspgadmin@tirisdspgserver:wsiNTobyx8opPo2imfCB@tirisdspgserver.postgres.database.azure.com/mav', Empty DataFrame\nColumns: [swing_id]\nIndex: []], (<class 'dict'>, [['engine_kwargs', (<class 'dict'>, [])], ['index_col', 'start_time']])), Empty DataFrame\nColumns: [swing_id]\nIndex: [], 'from_delayed'), 5)")
distributed.comm.utils - ERROR - ('Could not serialize object of type tuple.', "(<function safe_head at 0x00000000053B88B0>, (<function check_meta at 0x0000000005387EE0>, (<function apply at 0x0000000002AB3280>, <function _read_sql_chunk at 0x0000000005450AF0>, [<sqlalchemy.sql.selectable.Select at 0x99f8ca0; Select object>, 'postgresql://tirisdspgadmin@tirisdspgserver:wsiNTobyx8opPo2imfCB@tirisdspgserver.postgres.database.azure.com/mav', Empty DataFrame\nColumns: [swing_id]\nIndex: []], (<class 'dict'>, [['engine_kwargs', (<class 'dict'>, [])], ['index_col', 'start_time']])), Empty DataFrame\nColumns: [swing_id]\nIndex: [], 'from_delayed'), 5)")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\distributed\comm\utils.py", line 34, in _to_frames
    protocol.dumps(
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\distributed\protocol\core.py", line 50, in dumps
    data = {
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\distributed\protocol\core.py", line 51, in <dictcomp>
    key: serialize(
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\distributed\protocol\serialize.py", line 277, in serialize
    raise TypeError(msg, str(x)[:10000])
TypeError: ('Could not serialize object of type tuple.', "(<function safe_head at 0x00000000053B88B0>, (<function check_meta at 0x0000000005387EE0>, (<function apply at 0x0000000002AB3280>, <function _read_sql_chunk at 0x0000000005450AF0>, [<sqlalchemy.sql.selectable.Select at 0x99f8ca0; Select object>, 'postgresql://tirisdspgadmin@tirisdspgserver:wsiNTobyx8opPo2imfCB@tirisdspgserver.postgres.database.azure.com/mav', Empty DataFrame\nColumns: [swing_id]\nIndex: []], (<class 'dict'>, [['engine_kwargs', (<class 'dict'>, [])], ['index_col', 'start_time']])), Empty DataFrame\nColumns: [swing_id]\nIndex: [], 'from_delayed'), 5)")
distributed.batched - ERROR - Error in batched write
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\distributed\batched.py", line 93, in _background_send
    nbytes = yield self.comm.write(
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\distributed\comm\tcp.py", line 223, in write
    frames = await to_frames(
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\distributed\comm\utils.py", line 54, in to_frames
    return _to_frames()
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\distributed\comm\utils.py", line 34, in _to_frames
    protocol.dumps(
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\distributed\protocol\core.py", line 50, in dumps
    data = {
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\distributed\protocol\core.py", line 51, in <dictcomp>
    key: serialize(
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\distributed\protocol\serialize.py", line 277, in serialize
    raise TypeError(msg, str(x)[:10000])
TypeError: ('Could not serialize object of type tuple.', "(<function safe_head at 0x00000000053B88B0>, (<function check_meta at 0x0000000005387EE0>, (<function apply at 0x0000000002AB3280>, <function _read_sql_chunk at 0x0000000005450AF0>, [<sqlalchemy.sql.selectable.Select at 0x99f8ca0; Select object>, 'postgresql://tirisdspgadmin@tirisdspgserver:wsiNTobyx8opPo2imfCB@tirisdspgserver.postgres.database.azure.com/mav', Empty DataFrame\nColumns: [swing_id]\nIndex: []], (<class 'dict'>, [['engine_kwargs', (<class 'dict'>, [])], ['index_col', 'start_time']])), Empty DataFrame\nColumns: [swing_id]\nIndex: [], 'from_delayed'), 5)")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./project-name/src/points_bulk_scripts/extract_features.py", line 24, in <module>
    print(swings.head())
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\core.py", line 1006, in head
    return self._head(n=n, npartitions=npartitions, compute=compute, safe=True)
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\core.py", line 1039, in _head
    result = result.compute()
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\dask\base.py", line 167, in compute
    (result,) = compute(self, traverse=False, **kwargs)
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\dask\base.py", line 452, in compute
    results = schedule(dsk, keys, **kwargs)
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\distributed\client.py", line 2725, in get
    results = self.gather(packed, asynchronous=asynchronous, direct=direct)
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\distributed\client.py", line 1986, in gather
    return self.sync(
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\distributed\client.py", line 832, in sync
    return sync(
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\distributed\utils.py", line 340, in sync
    raise exc.with_traceback(tb)
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\distributed\utils.py", line 324, in f
    result[0] = yield future
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File ".\.conda\envs\project-name\lib\site-packages\distributed\client.py", line 1852, in _gather
    raise exc
concurrent.futures._base.CancelledError: ('head-1-5-from-delayed-97944bbb0c6f5129ccb48a1f7c36d62b', 0)
```

The oddest part if I don't create the `client`, then the dataframe is computed corrected:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
response = dd.read_sql_table(table=<SQLAlchemy query>, uri='uri', schema='schema', index_col='index')
print(response.head())
```

Plus, if I read the whole table, without querying it works with the client:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.distributed import Client

client = Client()
response = dd.read_sql_table(table=<SQLAlchemy table>, uri='uri', schema='schema', index_col='index')
print(response.head())
```

---

**Additional information**

Version:

```
dask                      2.30.0                     py_0
dask-core                 2.30.0                     py_0
dask-labextension         3.0.0                      py_0
python                    3.8.5                h5fd99cc_1
```

`client.get_versions(check=True)`:

```
{
    'scheduler': {
        'host': {
            'python': '3.8.5.final.0',
            'python-bits': 64,
            'OS': 'Windows',
            'OS-release': '7',
            'machine': 'AMD64',
            'processor': 'Intel64 Family 6 Model 94 Stepping 3, GenuineIntel',
            'byteorder': 'little',
            'LC_ALL': 'None',
            'LANG': 'None'
        },
        'packages': {
            'python': '3.8.5.final.0',
            'dask': '2.30.0',
            'distributed': '2.30.1',
            'msgpack': '1.0.0',
            'cloudpickle': '1.6.0',
            'tornado': '6.0.4',
            'toolz': '0.11.1',
            'numpy': '1.19.2',
            'lz4': None,
            'blosc': None
        }
    },
    'workers': {
        'tcp://127.0.0.1:57813': {
            'host': {
                'python': '3.8.5.final.0',
                'python-bits': 64,
                'OS': 'Windows',
                'OS-release': '7',
                'machine': 'AMD64',
                'processor': 'Intel64 Family 6 Model 94 Stepping 3, GenuineIntel',
                'byteorder': 'little',
                'LC_ALL': 'None',
                'LANG': 'None'
            },
            'packages': {
                'python': '3.8.5.final.0',
                'dask': '2.30.0',
                'distributed': '2.30.1',
                'msgpack': '1.0.0',
                'cloudpickle': '1.6.0',
                'tornado': '6.0.4',
                'toolz': '0.11.1',
                'numpy': '1.19.2',
                'lz4': None,
                'blosc': None
            }
        }
    },
    'client': {
        'host': {
            'python': '3.8.5.final.0',
            'python-bits': 64,
            'OS': 'Windows',
            'OS-release': '7',
            'machine': 'AMD64',
            'processor': 'Intel64 Family 6 Model 94 Stepping 3, GenuineIntel',
            'byteorder': 'little',
            'LC_ALL': 'None',
            'LANG': 'None'
        },
        'packages': {
            'python': '3.8.5.final.0',
            'dask': '2.30.0',
            'distributed': '2.30.1',
            'msgpack': '1.0.0',
            'cloudpickle': '1.6.0',
            'tornado': '6.0.4',
            'toolz': '0.11.1',
            'numpy': '1.19.2',
            'lz4': None,
            'blosc': None
        }
    }
}
```

`schema` class

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer, TIMESTAMP, Boolean
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base


class Schema(declarative_base()):

    __tablename__ = "table_name"

    datetime = Column(TIMESTAMP, primary_key=True)
    id = Column(String, primary_key=True)
```

Comment: Can you share your query statement, or the simplest form of it that appears to fail?

Comment: I have edited the answer to include the query in its simplest form, it is a `WHERE datetime BETWEEN start_dt AND end_dt`

Comment: by the way, as well as returning an exception, did your worker survive or die during evaluation?

Comment: ping - this is an interesting detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is this part of your query:

```
.select_from(schema)
```

where `schema` references a real DB connection.

You should instead refer to a completely abstract expression by using string tables, schemas and columns. For example, this from the tests

```
from sqlalchemy import sql
query = sql.select([sql.column("number"), sql.column("name")]).select_from(
        sql.table("test")
    )
```

(I think